# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Apps are disabled on this site

Tags: 2013, solution-deployment, app

We have installed SharePoint Server 2013 on a Windows Server 2008 machine. In our development environment we have installed Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 7 machine and have installed Office Development Tools to develop SharePoint 2013 web parts.

We are able to link to the site on the remote server, but after saying "Deploy solution" it's displaying this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Apps
>   are disabled on this site.

Please help us with this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Before you can deploy a SharePoint hosted app to your SharePoint Preview development environment you have to configure an isolated app domain.

like this :

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923%28v=office.15%29

Hops it helps!!

Answer (score -4):

This link will help you

[Install App for SharePoint](http://www.mavention.nl/blog/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-install-app-for-sharepoint-app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer a description of the solution here, and provide a link just for reference. Links alone are of limited use to users of the site particularly as they might change.